# Flags for ability system

Tags: design-patterns, game-development

I would like to prepare an ability config system where I'll be able to construct new ability just from values/flags:

```json
{
Name: "Passive Health Regeneration",
Active: false,
Affectable: "Health",
TickTime: .1,
TickAmount: -1,
Value: 10
}
```

But I would like to prevent usage of unhandy/useless flags so maybe there are some known good practices about it?

Answer (score 1):

One possible design is a [configuration mini-language AKA domain-specific language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) that builds an [entity-component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) entities.

It's not very clear what are "useless flags". I consider that DSL [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) (if you use [internal DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language#External_and_Embedded_Domain_Specific_Languages) which is easier), or DSL parser, if you go with external configuration, raise an error if they encounter an invalid flag/component.